# Finding cause of faint burning smell in active PA speaker

Tags: audio, switch-mode-power-supply, repair, troubleshooting

I play electric percussion in local theatres.  I use an active PA speaker with a 12" driver and a tweeter: a Wharfedale Pro EVP-X12P, which I bought in 2011.

I tilt it on a guitar amp stand, to point the fairly-directional tweeter at my ears so I can hear it properly.

[image: speaker tilted on stand]

Recently, I've noticed a faint burning smell when it is turned on.  The smell makes me think of the 1970s somehow (?!)... perhaps this is burning wood.

Also, I think it sounds very slightly distorted at times -- but it might have always been this way -- I've never been 100% happy with it.

It is my only working speaker, and I'm a bit worried that it'll fail when I need it for a show.

I'm comfortable with digital circuits, but understanding analogue stuff is more of a struggle for me.  But I'm learning a fair bit by trying to puzzle out this issue.

Taking the thing apart, there are two cabinets, fairly carefully sealed away from each other.  The driver cabinet (which also contains the crossover board) seems fine as far as I can tell.

The cabinet at the back holds the preamp board, the (switched mode) power supply and the power amp, all mounted on a metal plate.  In this picture, the PSU is uppermost in the black cage, the power amp is beneath it and the preamp board is furthest away from the camera.  When installed, the preamp board is lowest, and the black cage fits into the recess in the cabinet above.

[image: Inside the rear cabinet]

The rear cabinet has some black stains inside.  I suspect they are scorch marks, and the smell I've detected is slightly toasted MDF, but I'm not sure.  Alternatively, the stains might be stray black spray paint from manufacture (the black metal plate?).

[image: Black stains in cabinet]

Looking upwards, there's also a smaller black stain at the top:

[image: Smaller stain at the top]

If they are burns, it is odd that the stains are mostly at the bottom of the cabinet, because the relatively hot running PSU and power amp are *above*, in the recess.  The nearest board to the stains is the preamp board, but that's low power stuff.

Here are the preamp and power amp boards, mounted on the plate:

[image: Preamp and power amp boards on the plate]

And the power supply board:

[image: Power supply board]

Following my nose, I think the smell is from the PSU board.  I did notice this perhaps slightly melted IC, labelled `U2`, with some gunk on the PCB around it (although perhaps that's just solder flux?).

[image: Possibly melted U2]

Here's the schematic of the preamp (highlighted) and the power amp (on the right):

[image: Preamp and power amp schematic]

And here's the power supply schematic.  Some details are missing.  On the physical board, the 8 pin IC is labelled `HIGH SUN DT5268S`.  `BR1` is labelled `KBJ 2510`.  The possibly melted `U2` is shown as `PC817B` on the diagram, but the physical part seems to be marked something like `PC-A7K 1 65-V K`.

[image: Power supply schematic]

I was ready to replace `U2`, but thought I'd try and verify the issue further first, especially given the mismatch between the schematic and the part markings.

I carefully hooked it all up (laid out on a piece of ply), playing some quietish audio, and tried to locate hot components using a (cheap) IR thermometer.

- Everything on the preamp board is around 28°C.
- The power amp board is mostly around 30°C, apart from `Q17` (32-37°C) and `C6` (36°C).
- On the PSU board, things are more variable.  Most components are at < 50°C.  `U2` actually seems relatively fine: only 38°C.  The hottest components are `T2` (60°C), `R25` (72°C) and `R24` (80°C).

I turned up the audio for a few minutes, and the PSU components I've listed got a little hotter.

The high (?) temperatures of `R25` and `R24` worried me.  In the schematic, they are marked as 39K, 2W, so I measured the voltage across them.  But I measure only 162V DC... so with \$W = V^2 / R\$, they are dissipating 0.67W, well under the rated 2W.  So I guess those temps are normal.

The PSU output voltages seem ok: I measure -67.3V, +67.3V, -15.3V, +15.1V (with everything connected, but no audio playing).

There is what I assume is a test point, labelled `J1_110V` in the schematic and on the board.  There, I measure 140.6V AC rather than 110V, so perhaps this is out of whack?  But this might be my cheap multimeter.  Also `C12`-`C14` are marked on the schematic as `680U`, but the actual components are marked 470µF, so perhaps that accounts for this discrepancy.

So -- I'm a bit stumped.  The manufacturer will sell me a replacement PSU board, but I'm not sure that's the issue or in fact if there really is an issue.

Perhaps the actual cause of this is inadequate ventilation, due to me tilting it.  In which case I need to think about adding a fan.  But I would appreciate advice or thoughts.  Thanks for reading.

---

**Update**

Ok, so pretty strong agreement here (from 7 people so far) that the the stains are actually just paint - thank you all.

But there are a few signs that the `U2` optocoupler may be starting to fail.  I think a failure there could prevent the system from completing power up, and I need a reliably working amp very soon for upcoming shows.

So I have ordered a replacement PSU board.  I will try and compare that (known-hopefully-good) board with the original one and repeat my measurements to learn more.

Thanks everyone.  Appreciate this helpful community.  I will report back here if/when I learn more.

Comment: It looks like black paint to me.

Comment: have you looked for signs of overheating on the underside of the power supply PCB?

Comment: How is the capacitor just adjacent to U2 doing? Is it leaking electrolyte?

Answer (score 2):

The U2 optocoupler should be checked for a short.  If it isn't shorted, and assuming you have checked the underside of the board for any visible faults, if any components aren't getting really hot, then I would suspect the source of the odor to be some chemical they used during the manufacturing process.  If this is the case, then you might consider coating the component side of the circuit board(avoiding any components that actually do need to dissipate heat, such as the heatsinks) with some spray lacquer to seal in the scent.

In regard to the black patches inside the cabinet, I have seen this many times, and it is just overspray.  If the discoloration were due to minor heating, the patches would be brown in color.  If the discoloration were due to more extreme heating and they were black in color, then the surface would be visibly physically damaged.

Slightly tilting your stage monitor should have absolutely no effect on it's operation or reliability.

Comment: Since we don't normally recommend parts here, I'll leave this as a comment, but Mouser has your part for $0.39 USD:  https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/395/TPC817%20SERIES_C1612-1114502.pdf

Comment: Thank you for explaining the likely colours of patches - that's really helpful and reassuring.

Comment: Actually I think the value of `R29` is `10R`, not `10K` (sorry for the poor quality schematic image).  If so, could be 1.5A and 22.5W?

Comment: Re: the `U2` part - thank you for the Mouser data sheet. I can see that's `PC817B`, which matches the schematic. That data sheet says the physical product should be marked `817B`, but I see something different... perhaps `PC-A7K 1 65-V K`? Are physical markings typically this different? (I can ask this as a separate question if more appropriate.) There's also a discrepancy between the values of `C12`-`C14` on the schematic (`680U`) and physically (470µF), so I'm not totally sure of the schematic accuracy.

Comment: @Ashley - You are correct!  I hadn't scaled the schematic up enough to distinguish between the "R" and "K".  I will update my answer.  As far as the package markings go, optocouplers(like capacitors) are sometimes quite forgiving when substituting parts depending on their specific use in the circuit.  The part number could be an OEM marking for an electrically equivalent part, or could be a similar substitute used by the manufacturer due to pricing or availability.  Likewise, when capacitors are used as DC power bus filters(like C12-C15) their exact value is not necessarily critical if close.

Comment: Thank you - that's reassuring. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ashley - Great! Please let us know how it turns out by editing your question and adding an addendum.